# We want to know why the Microsoft Graph API takes over 24 hours to update before data is accessible to be queried

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365

We are using the Microsoft Graph API to gather data on our users within our organization.

We want to know why the Microsoft Graph API takes over 24 hours to update before data is accessible to be queried.

Comment: can you add more detail about what attributes you are seeing not being updated?  It could be data from on-prem AD is not synced with AAD for a period of time for example.  But it really depends on what data/attributes you are talking about.

Comment: We are using the Usage reports for email activity and teams activity.